# win7 - play audio on correct display device

Tags: windows-7, audio, multiple-monitors

How can i achieve that applications audio is played on device depending on which display it is shown?

I often have my tv connected with my laptop via HDMI and i want that the applications sound is played on the tv only if the applications window is on the tv and vice versa.

Is this even possible? And if - how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to happen when the application is on your laptop screen? Do you want the audio to play when other applications are on the TV? What do you want the default behavior to be?

Comment: i do not want to mute some application.but the sound should come from the directionon that the app is running. its confusing to get the sounde of some application that is running on the laptop right in front of one from the distant TV that runs some series or film.

Comment: @sunk818 why did you removed your answer? it lloked promising since the changeappvolume command also has a sounddevice parameter. but i can't test it until tomorrow (or the day after)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [nircmd](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/muteappvolume.html) and use the muteappvolume command to turn on and turn off audio. That may be easier than trying to find a program that will play audio only if it is in a certain monitor.